# Red texts in the TYPO3 backend after update to 9.5.x

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

after i updated TYPO3 from 8.x to 9.5.x appears some red texts in the backend. How can i remove it?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well,

## It's not a Bug, It's Feature!!

You must have enabled TYPO3 backend debug, that way you will see the field name right after field label. You can disable from `LocalConfiguration.php` or from TYPO3 backend it self.

1. From `LocalConfiguration.php`: Just open `LocalConfiguration.php` located in `typo3conf`. Find `[BE]['debug'] => 'true'` and switch it back to `[BE]['debug'] => 'false'`
2. From TYPO3 backend:

   - Go to `settings` module under `Admin Tool`.
   - Find `Configuration Presets` and click on `Choose Preset`
   - You will find `Debug settings` there, click on it and switch to `Live`

Basically, both done the same thing. TYPO3 will disable debug mode and only critical warnings and errors will be displayed.

That's it!

Comment: That did the job! Thank you! :)